# C sizeof(xx) issue... ??? USB device descriptor

Tags: c, usb, cortex-m

I am writing USB device firmware... i have the following struct typedef

```
typedef struct  {
    uint8_t bLength;
    uint8_t bDescriptorType;
    uint16_t wTotalLength;
    uint8_t bNumInterfaces;
    uint8_t bConfigurationValue;
    uint8_t iConfiguration;
    uint8_t bmAttributes;
    uint8_t bMaxPower;
} usbtmc_config_descriptor;
```

By my count, this is 9 bytes, however when I do this

```
sprintf(temp, "size of config is %02x, %d", sizeof(usbtmc_config_descriptor), sizeof(usbtmc_config_descriptor));
prints(temp);
```

terminal spits out the following

```
size of config is 0a, 10
```

I am absolutely flumuxxed...
If you are wondering the prints() method is just a method I wrote to print out a string through the UART to hyperterminal followed by \r\n for ease of use...

here is the whole method for those who think it is important

```
void prints(const char* message){
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(&g_mss_uart0, ((uint8_t *)message));
    unsigned char newline[2] = {0x0A, 0x0D};
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(&g_mss_uart0, newline);
}
```

some background info which may pertain to the situation, this is firmware code for a Cortex M3, Smartfusion Soc, using SoftConsole with GCC 4.4.1 CodeSourcery tools for compilation...

how is it possible that I am not getting a total of 9 for sizeof????
What am I missing???

Comment: a struct will always be a power of 2 in size(rounded up).  The size and alignment will be according to the largest member/field within the struct.

Answer (score 2):

The largest element in you struct has two bytes. It has to be aligned at an offset divisible by 2.

Imagine you struct having a sizeof == 9, then if you have an array of these structs, the second element in the array will not have its member: `wTotalLength` correctly aligned.

For example:

Sizeof is 9, you have an array of structs `usbtmc_config_descriptor[2]` and you start at the address 0. The next element in the array of structs comes at the address 9. The member `wTotalLength` is at offset +2 which makes its address 11. Not correctly aligned.

Address of `usbtmc_config_descriptor[0]` is 0

Address of `usbtmc_config_descriptor[1]` is 9

Address of `usbtmc_config_descriptor[1].wTotalLength` is 11

Answer (score 1):

You observe *structure padding* (depending on the processor and its [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)). See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968468/padding-in-structures-in-c)

You have a member `wTotalLength` which is of type `uint16_t`. It has to be two-bytes aligned on your architecture. So the entire structure has to be aligned to two bytes. Hence an extra gap of one byte is appended. Without such a gap, the odd elements of an array of `usbtmc_config_descriptor`-s would be misaligned. And accessing them might make a `SIGBUS` or [alignment trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464254/841108).